# Commerce CP Shipping Errors

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping, plugin-craftcommerce4

Craft Commerce 4.0.2 trying to EDIT shipping rules and getting this kind of error :

`Cannot assign string to property craft\commerce\models\ShippingRule::$maxTotal of type float`

[image]

Anyone getting this kind of error ? Since we're just before going live, I will remove all rules and re-enter them, but that's really unfortunate.

Comment: Yes, it's bug on commerce, but looks like they have a fix but not yet release it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We'll be waiting on this fix ! In the meantime, I managed to enter data and updating directly in the database.